# How to get elements of array in mongoose.methods with deep population?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I need get elements (or the first element) of array  from a callback of `mongoose.methods` with deep poulation

```
  { _id: 5994e4157aca6a0bb5e911e8,
   username: 'user1',
   roles:
    { account:
       { _id: 5994c2dbacd0b30b6f5bae90,
         groups: [Object] }      // need to get elements of this array
```

Method

```
  userSchema.methods.accountGroupOfUser = function accountGroupOfUser(callback) {
    return mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
      .findById(this.id)
      .populate( {path: 'roles.account', model: 'Account', select: 'groups'} )
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null);
        }
        return callback(null, user);
      });
  };
```

So it gets the main `User` document and populates `groups` field from referred `Account` document.
I want to use this field in Express middleware,  and get it in the callback

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = {};
  res.locals.user.accountGroupOfUser = req.user && req.user.accountGroupOfUser(function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return (err);
    }
    // Here is where I'm trying to get the items
    return (user.roles.account.groups.forEach(function (err, item) {
      return (item); // not working
      // return (user.roles.account.groups[0]) not worikng too
    }));
  });
  next();
});
```

Calling `user.roles.account.groups[0]` returns a value when you make a regular query and use it in templates, but not working in a callback of `mongoose.methods` and always returns `[object Object]` instead of actual values.
I need to get only the value which must be stored in `accountGroupOfUser`, how to get it in a callback?

**Update**

The schemas

```
  // user -> roles.account ref to Account model 
  var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    roles: {
      account: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' }, 
    },
 });

  // account -> ref to AccountGroup
  var accountSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    groups: [{ type: String, ref: 'AccountGroup' }], 
  });

  // accountGroup -> is populated in account.groups
exports = module.exports = function(app, mongoose) {
  var accountGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String },  // slugified name of a group can use this as group name too
    name: { type: String, default: '' },  // group name
    permissions: [{ name: String, permit: Boolean }]
  });
```

Comment: Could you please add your schemas for all of your models?

Comment: @Francisco Flores added shemas as you asked

Comment: @Francisco Flores Any ideas? Could you see this please? Maybe I misudestood the whole concept of methods and I can'd make dynamic queries like that? Basically what I need is that groups name can be accessable in templates in all app via res.locals