# Express.js: What are possible ways to set Mongoose query field accessable globally to the templates (hanldlebars)?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

For example in this query:

```
 User.findById(req.user._id)
      .populate( {path: 'roles.account', populate: { path: 'groups', select: 'name'} })
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null);
        }
        return callback(null, user);
      });
```

I can retrieve the name of a group in my templates like `{{user.roles.account.groups.[0].name}}` if I pass it to `res.render` function only for a specific route.

How can can I get this value (not the whole document) be avialable globally?  I tried  to set a method for User model and pass it in a callback to `res.locals`, but it didn't worked. It has to be dynamic, depending on `req.user._id`.

Are there other ways to make it global?

Comment: From the looks of the code, i assume you are using a function and passing it the `req`, right? If so, why not write the query inside the handler and you can use  `res.render('viewName', {user: user})` in the callback instead of  `return callback(null,user)`

Comment: This is what you do when you want to render specific view, and what I want is this value to be accessable in all views in the app, with similar functionality like, for eample, if you setting something in in res.locals or app.locals

Comment: I see, And you tried to put it inside an `app.use(req, res, next) { }` function and set it to the `res.locals` ? is that what you meant by tried to set a method for User model ?

Comment: Yes. i tried to set it to the middleware, but had some problems with it  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45928303/7134027). So maybe there is simplier way todo this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i looked at the link you provided and noticed a couple of things.

First in the `app.use()` function, you are calling `next()` after the async callback and not inside it. so it's called before the the async finisheds.

Second is in the `forEach` function, you wrote an `err` argument, which it does not have according to [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

I have created the schemas and this code worked fine for me with no need for another method :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    User.findById(req.user._id)
      .populate({ path: 'roles.account', model: 'Account', populate: { path: 
               'groups', select: 'name' } })
      .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return err
        }
        res.locals.groups = user.roles.account.groups
        next()
      })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Comment: Good  solution, thanks. Only you need to use user.roles.account.groups[0].name or enter it like {{#each groups}}this{{/each}} because it is an array